# Is there a free vaccine or medicinal product database?

Tags: medications, vaccination, research

Is there a database that allows me to query for available vaccine products by ingredients?

For instance, I want to find an available vaccine product that contains "Streptococcus pneumoniae antigens" AND "Haemophilus influenzae type B antigens".

So far I used a spreadsheet provided by WHO which, however, is not complete (available here: https://www.who.int/immunization/programmes_systems/procurement/mi4a/platform/module1/en/).

I also used a european database for medicines (https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/medicines/field_ema_web_categories%253Aname_field/Human?search_api_views_fulltext=streptococcus%20pneumoniae%20and%20haemophilus%20influenzae) that was not helpful either.

Moreover, I used a national register, which is more precise and helpful at finding vaccine products with the single ingredients available within Germany but did not take me further.

Comment: You ask about "ingredients," which implies everything in the vial, including inactive ingredients such as preservatives. Also, including the word "antigen" in your search wouldn't find RNA vaccines. Is that your intent or are you really just looking for different combinations of vaccines?

Comment: Just looking for different combinations. Not for application purpose, but for standardization of data structures adopting semantic standards / terminology (i.e. SNOMED CT).

Answer (score 2):

The US' National Institute of Health maintains the [Daily Med database](https://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/index.cfm), which is searchable by active and inactive ingredients.

---